# Any way to have adb remember devices once connected wirelessly?

Tags: android, adb

The whole point of setting up wireless adb was so that I would not have to connect it to via usb everytime.

via this question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727/4645236 I started wireless debugging with a device. Worked great! Super convenient without a doubt.

Now I am wondering if there is a way keep this setting and not have to plug in every time...

I'd like to wirelessly connect to the device via the PC terminal in one command, 
even if the server has been killed and restarted. 
Is this possible? Or do I have to use a script?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the ADB server having been killed and restarted, rather it has to do with the ADB daemon on the device having been restarted.  When that happens, a stock, secured device simply will not permit TCP connection until you use the USB connection to re-enable it - and there is nothing you can do about that while it remains stock and secured.

Comment: @Chris Stratton How hard is it to unstock and unsecure it, then resecure it with an unstock build? This device is on the way out anyways... 
Once I have a custom build on there can I accept a TCP connection without usb?

Comment: That is utterly unanswerable without knowing what it is...

Comment: @ChrisStratton it is a galaxy S5, sprint is the carrier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the ADB daemon on your device is not restarted you can connect to your device via WiFi (ADB over tcp) without it connected through usb.
if it restarts, you will have to connect to the device via usb and run:

`adb tcpip <port>`

Comment: No Guaranties, but as long as you don't restart the daemon manually (i.e. run 'adb usb ' or 'adb root') nor reboot, you should be OK...

Comment: Take a look at this, it explains it nicely:
[drop-that-embarrassing-usb-cable-when-you-develop-on-android](http://www.chentir.com/2012/11/10/drop-that-embarrassing-usb-cable-when-you-develop-on-android/).

Here you can also find some answers [http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1825359](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1825359)

Answer (score 0):

simply turn on your wireless adb on the device and connect however you do so wirelessly is all it takes. so example is (adb connect 192.168.1.xxx). thats it. Shouldn't have any memory issues.

Comment: "turn on your wireless adb on the device" Not sure what you mean by this, I've only turned on adb via terminal. I do not see anything about adb in my phones settings?

Comment: Depending on your phone, you might have to check your developer settings. If it's not there, you will have to download an app or enable it via terminal (on your device). Here is a link to the wireless adb I use. Here is a link to the wireless adb app i use. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rockolabs.adbkonnect

Comment: Yes, Chris is correct. I did assume that you were rooted. Otherwise I don't believe this is possible